# Do unused use statements decrease performance?

Tags: php, performance, php-internals

I want to know if unused use statements in my class affect **performance** of my php website?

Does php include all classes in beginning or when need it? If second choice then I think it doesn't affect performance of my system.

For Example: **Use statement 'DbConnector' is not used**

```
use model\adapter\DbConnector;
```

Comment: All questions like these have the same answer: profile it.

Comment: If you are not using it, than why to keep it? It only makes mess in your code.

Comment: I am alredy removing unused uses and I wonder if it will increase performance.

Comment: There's no valid reason to be sloppy, but it won't impact performance in any meaningful way.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

No, the `use` statement does not provoke the the class be loaded (it does not even trigger an autoloader).

It just declares a short name for a class. I *assume* the cost in terms of CPU and RAM is in the order of a few CPU cycles and a few bytes.

Comment: There is a scenario I am fighting, where because of too many use aliases and require_once calls, the opcode cache gives up resulting in a huge performance penalty. Without use aliasing but keeping all require_once calls, it all works fine. On PHP 7.0.x, didn't test others.

Comment: Also, this benchmark says fully qualified is always faster: https://veewee.github.io/blog/optimizing-php-performance-by-fq-function-calls/

Comment: Feel free to add your own aswer, however I am under the impression that you have misunderstood the point of the question. We are discussing the potential cost of *unused* `use` clauses, not the cost of *actually used* `use` clauses.

Comment: I don't have an answer to make, I have a comment. Also, I'm a long time user, I guess I should've known by now! I didn't say the statements are actually used.

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of PHP, PHP 7 and especially PHP 7.2, are very good at optimizing code when it's complied into byte code. Unsed `use` statements are just stripped away by the compiler and will not even execute. Therefore it should not have any impact whatsoever. The compiler might use a few more CPU cycles while parsing the file but if you use OPCache there will be no effect on performance. The file will only be loaded when they are needed.